# one to one multiple foreign key from same table EF Core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Stuck on write code for table relation below :

```
public class PersonModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string Address{ get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateofBirth{ get; set; }
    public GenderEnum Gender{ get; set; }

    public PersonDetailModel PersonDetail { get; set; }
    public PersonDetailModel PersonDetailforMate { get; set; }
}

public class PersonDetailModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public int? MateID { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber{ get; set; }
    public string OfficeAddress{ get; set; }
    public MarriageStatusEnum MarriageStatus{ get; set; }

    public PersonModel Person { get; set; }
    public PersonModel PersonforMate { get; set; }
}
```

I use Fluent API :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PersonModel>()
            .HasOne(d => d.PersonDetailModel)
            .WithOne(p => p.PersonModel)
            .HasForeignKey<PersonDetailModel>(d => d.PersonID);

modelBuilder.Entity<PersonDetailModel>()
            .HasOne(d => d.PersonModel)
            .WithOne(p => p.PersonDetailModel)
            .HasForeignKey<PersonDetailModel>(d => d.MateID);
```

when i build, it getting error

```
Cannot create a relationship between 'PersonModel.PersonDetailforMate' and 'PersonDetailModel.Person', because there already is a relationship between 'PersonModel.PersonDetail' and 'PersonDetailModel.Person'. Navigation properties can only participate in a single relationship.
```

there are several references for similar problem :

- [Multiple foreign keys pointing to same table in Entity Framework 4.1 code first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015964/multiple-foreign-keys-pointing-to-same-table-in-entity-framework-4-1-code-first)
- [2 Foreign Keys as Primary Key using EF Core 2.0 Code First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50398457/2-foreign-keys-as-primary-key-using-ef-core-2-0-code-first)
- [EF multiple foreign key relationship on same primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30075433/ef-multiple-foreign-key-relationship-on-same-primary-key)

but those are for one-to-many relationship.

*sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation in my project, and this is what I ended up doing:

```
public class PersonModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string Address{ get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateofBirth{ get; set; }
    public GenderEnum Gender{ get; set; }

    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PersonID ")]
    public PersonDetailModel PersonDetail { get; set; }

    public int? MateID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("MateID")]
    public PersonDetailModel PersonDetailforMate { get; set; }
}

public class PersonDetailModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber{ get; set; }
    public string OfficeAddress{ get; set; }
    public MarriageStatusEnum MarriageStatus{ get; set; }
}
```

so `PersonModel` would have two foreign keys to `PersonDetailModel`. I am using `ForeignKey` attribute to explicitly tell EF which foreign key belongs to which relationship - if you use the `Foreignkey` attribute, you won't need the Fluent API Configurations...

The above code will build you a `PersonModel` table in the DB, with `PersonId` and `MateId` columns as foreign key.

Comment: i think it's a cool idea. but, it will change my master table (person). and i cant get mate's name, address and other detail